# POST request from iPhone to Django

Tags: iphone, django, http-post

I'm trying to send a POST request from iPhone to Django, but for some reason I can't. The request is sent, but the server doesn't receive it properly.

1. What is the regular expression that accepts POST? In my case, I use this one: `/messages/a/s=person1&r=person2&c=hello/`.
2. How do I retrieve the POST arguments in the Django view? `request.POST['s']` should work?

Thanks.

Comment: POST data is not sent in the URL. No regex is required.

Comment: Also, if you were to send the data in the URL in the GET format, you would need a `?` at the start of the parameter list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POST parameters are not part of the URL, so your regex should simply detail the main part of the url you want to receive it on. To take your example, change it to `/messages/a/`. Then, in your "messages" app, have a view/function called `a`: that one will be reached on receiving any POST (or GET, which you're currently (almost) depicting in your url) to that location.

The arguments can then indeed be retrieved using `request.POST['keyname']`. To make things more convenient, supply a default value when getting the data so you need less error checking: `request.POST.get('keyname', None)`. This will get the value of `keyname` when available, or `None` otherwise.

The posting itself... depends on more code then you're currently showing. Can't say anything about that with your current question.

Answer (score 3):

That URL you've pasted in will pass the data through the `request.GET` dictionary. If you want to change your iPhone app to POST data, you'll have to share your code.

Comment: This isn't true - the URL he posted doesn't have a ? in it, nothing will be in the request.GET dictionary